# NextJS Image component with fixed witdth and auto height

Tags: reactjs, next.js, tailwind-css, nextjs-image

I am using NextJS Image component. I want the image to fill 100% width and take as much height as it needs to maintain the aspect ratio. I have tried many different variations of this code but it will not work unless I define a fixed height on the parent div.

```
export default function PhotoCard({ img }: Props) {
      return (
        <div className="relative w-full h-32 my-2">
          <Image alt={img.title} src={img.url} layout="fill" objectFit="cover" />
        </div>
      );
    }
```

This is the current behaviour
[image: images in app]

Comment: Try to set the image directly inside the `<Image />` tag.

Comment: did you find any fix for this?

Answer (score 97):

From Next.js 13, the [`next/image`](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next/image) component allows styling the underlying image directly using `style`/`className`. This means you can apply `width: 100%` and `height: auto` on the `Image` component directly.

```js
import Image from 'next/image';

<Image
    src={img1}
    width="0"
    height="0"
    sizes="100vw"
    style={{ width: '100%', height: 'auto' }}
/>
```

Or, if using Tailwind CSS.

```js
import Image from 'next/image';

<Image
    src={img1}
    width="0"
    height="0"
    sizes="100vw"
    className="w-full h-auto"
/>
```

---

Before Next.js 13, the above feature is only available through `next/future/image`, and from version 12.2, `next/future/image` was still experimental and can be enabled in `next.config.js` under the `experimental` flag.

```js
module.exports = {
    experimental: {
        images: {
            allowFutureImage: true
        }
    },
    // Other configs
}
```

Answer (score 8):

****For those who are getting the error like:****

```
 Image with src "image path" has either width or height modified, but not the other. If you use CSS to change the size of your image, also include the styles 'width: "auto"' or 'height: "auto"' to maintain the aspect ratio.
```

***Setting width and height attribute to 0 and adding style with your desired height or width and setting either of width or height to auto*** will fix the issue

```
             <Image
                src="image path"
                height={0}
                width={0}
                style={{width:'120px', height: "auto" }}
              />
```

Comment: This helped remove the error. Thank you for that. However, after applying height and width to 0, and applying Tailwind classes: `className="w-[300px] h-auto"`, the image is blurred. Any idea why that could be the case?..

Answer (score 5):

As Next.js has mentioned in their documentation, width and height properties are required in order to avoid layout shift, using layout="fill" will only fill the container height and width that is previously set. This basically means that in order to maintain the aspect ratio, you have to know the image height and width in advance.

Luckily though, Next.js also provided us a work around with this problem with an event called `onLoadingComplete`, which gives us an event parameter that contains both image natural height and width.

```
<Image
   layout="fill"
   src="/cat.jpg"
   onLoadingComplete={e => console.log(e)} // {naturalHeight: ..., naturalWidth: ...}
/>
```

There are plenty of options that you can do to maintain image aspect ratio with this information, like `useState` to set the height and the width of the element or make the image responsive, depends on your need. In any case, hope this was helpful.

Comment: This should be higher up! Setting only one dimension for images and auto-ing the other is a pretty common design in normal images, I wonder why NextJS can't support that feature more easily.

Comment: `layout` is deprecated https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next/legacy/image

Comment: @Mo. The future image component looks promising tbh.

Answer (score 2):

## 2023 Solution

If you load `image` from external `url` just remove `width` and `height` and use `fill`

```
<Image
      loading={"lazy"}
      fill
      src={post.image}
/>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have found a solution without using `next/future/image` and with using `css` with `width-[100%]` on the parent div like so.

```js
           <div
              className="mx-auto w-[100%] md:bg-card md:w-[720px] max-w-4/5"
              key={img.imageProps.src}
            >
              <Image
                placeholder="blur"
                {...img.imageProps}
                layout={'responsive'}
                alt={`${chapterData.chapterNumber} image`}
              />
            </div>
```

`{...img.imageProps}` is a object that looks like this that has original height and width.

```js
export type ImageProps = {
  blurDataURL: string;
  src: string;
  height: number;
  width: number;
  type?: string | undefined;
};
```

You can get these image props using something like `plaiceholder`, it comes loaded with `blurImage` data url.

```
const convertImages = async (image: string) => {
    const { base64, img } = await getPlaiceholder(image, { size: 14 });
    return {
      imageProps: {
        ...img,
        blurDataURL: base64,
      },
    };
  };
```

OR

You can create your own function to get the `height` and `width` for each image individually before displaying it, which is required by the next `<Image/>`
Hope this helps.

Answer (score -1):

You can try to set width and height with "%" way..

```
<Image src={image.url} alt={image.title} width="100%" height="100%" layout="responsive" objectFit="contain"/>
```

or you can set the width with the "vw" property like this..

```
<Image src={image.url} alt={image.title} width="100vw" height="100%" layout="responsive" objectFit="contain"/>
```