# How to have fixed witdth and height auto in Next JS image?

Tags: css, next.js, tailwind-css

I am trying to display list images that have a fixed width and use the original height of the image that is `100%`.
Similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69230343/nextjs-image-component-with-fixed-witdth-and-auto-height) here with no answer.

I have read these answers  [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65169431/how-to-set-the-next-image-component-to-100-height) and  tried them out. The images are there in the dom but out of the screen and does not show up.

The size of images varies eg. `1280x15141, 1280x14333`.
This is what I am trying to do from the docs [example](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/blob/canary/examples/image-component/pages/layout-fill.js).

```js
    <main className="mx-auto max-w-7xl ">
      <section className="flex flex-col">
        {chapter.images.map((img) => (
          <div key={img} style={{ position: 'relative', width: '768px', height: '100%' }}>
            <Image alt="Mountains" src={img} layout="fill" objectFit="contain" />
          </div>
        ))}
      </section>
    </main>
```

This ends up displaying no image but they are present in the dom.

[image: noimage]

Update:
As per suggestion I have added height.

```js
      <section className="flex flex-col">
        {chapter.images.map((img) => (
          <div key={img} style={{ position: 'relative', width: '768px', height: '100px' }}>
            <Image alt="Mountains" src={img} layout="fill" objectFit="contain" />
          </div>
        ))}
      </section>
```

[image: pic]

Plain `img` tag approach.
But if i use the images in `<img>` instead.
I am able to see the image and apply `width` to it with the height as the default.

```js
      <section className="flex flex-col gap-2">
        {chapter.images.map((img) => (
          <div key={img} className="mx-auto md:w-4/5">
            <img alt="Mountains" src={img} />
          </div>
        ))}
      </section>
```

But I want to use NextJs `Image`.
How can I do that?

Comment: It looks like the images have 0px height. Try setting some height on the container element, or use a fixed height rather than `100%`.

Comment: With height I am able to see the image, but they are small. I have updated the question.

Comment: Does this answer your question: [NextJS Image component with fixed witdth and auto height](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69230343/nextjs-image-component-with-fixed-witdth-and-auto-height)?

Comment: I have found a solution using` next/future/Image` and without it.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you're import path is incorrect

```
import mountains from '../../public/mountains.jpg'
```

Comment: Images are `urls` not static import.

Comment: If nothing is wrong with the path then probably try changing your css positions or adding a z-index of 1 or 2 to your image element. That could potentially also be a possibility of why things appear in the dom but are not visual.

Comment: I have tried it, still cant see the image

Comment: if possible, can you re simulate the code on stackblitz.com or share with me you're github so I can run it on my local and test.

Comment: Hi, just to update. I have found a workaround for this usings NextJs `12.2` `<Image src={src} witdh={786}/>` which is still in experimental. That accepts fixed width and no height. Its not a final fix but works for now.