# How to fix the aspect-ratio related issue in the Next JS 14 Image component?

Tags: css, reactjs, next.js

I tried to show the logo in the Next JS Image Component. but, showing this issue. I tried many ways. but, I couldn't fix this warning

Here is my simple code.

```js
<Link href="/">
  <Image src="/logo.svg" width={177.35} height={30} alt="Logo" />
</Link>
```

and, my warning below

[image]

I tried add to styles and tailwind classes. but, I couldn't clear this warning. Any ideas to fix this warning. I hope this fix is simple.

Comment: Have you tried adding `width: auto; height: auto;` to `<Link href="/">
  <Image src="/logo.svg" width={177.35} height={30} alt="Logo" />
</Link>`?

Comment: <Image src="/logo.svg"  style={{ width:177.35 , height:30 }} alt="Logo" />

Comment: I added. but, also this warning getting @NaveenNizam,

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69230343/nextjs-image-component-with-fixed-witdth-and-auto-height  related question

Comment: Thank you @NaveenNizam. It's working.

But,
I give the original SVG width and height. So, the warning appears. If I change the width or height the warning is gone. I don't know Why is this happening?